# How do troubleshoot AWS Beanstalk deployment of a React on Rails app?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails

Hi all and thanks for reading!

I'm brand new to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, and I'm attempting to deploy my Rails app, which has a React frontend

I'm deploying via the Elastic Beanstalk dashboard, and the health of my app is "Degraded"

When i request the last 100 lines from the logs, the errors I'm seeing are the following:

```
2019/04/01 14:32:24 [crit] 3153#0: *1268 connect() to unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream, client: 59.36.169.180, server: _, request: "POST /mm.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock:/mm.php", host: "54.71.247.127"
```

I would love any insight into what this error means AND/OR suggestions on what my next troubleshooting steps should be.

Generally speaking, as a beginner, I'm finding it difficult to figure out a systematic troubleshooting approach to deploying on AWS. I see a few tutorials that seem at least semi-applicable, but if anything goes wrong, then I'm left not knowing what resource to look up to figure out my problem. Any guidance regarding this would be so so appreciated!

Please let me know if I should include any additional info.

Comment: Any updates on this? Also having this problem too